# Are there stock Apple icon sets available for download?

Tags: ipad, icons

I see the same icons being used in many different apps (for example in a tab bar the icons for refresh, home, expand, etc). Is there a free download of these basic icons available from Apple, or do they have to be designed by each individual developer?
It seems strange to me that Apple go to great lengths for their apps to follow the HIG, but wouldn't supply at least the very basic set of icons, so users instinctively know what the button does. Ive had a quick search on Google, but nothing seems to come up directly from Apple, and most others are paid-for icons. Any ideas anyone??

***edit***

And as a side question, are two icon images needed to satisfy retina displays or will the app automatically 'downsize' a retina-display-happy icon for the normal display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the 'standard' icons you see, in `UIToolBar`s, for example, are Apple-designed. They are built in to the standard `UIBarButtonItem` class. To initialize one of these, you do something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSytemItem)...
```

What goes in `(UIBarButtonSystemItem)` could be:

> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemSave`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemReply`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemStop`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemPause`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo`
> - `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl`

Which are all the standard icons you see throughout iOS.

I got that list from the [`UIBarButtonItem` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBarButtonSystemItem). It contains things like screenshots and descriptions of use cases.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to reference to these from the storyboard (ie in the Bar Item properties - Image) or do I have to create a new subclass to load it in in code?

Comment: I believe it is in a bar button's IB properties. Look around- you'll know it when you see it.

Comment: Thanks - you have the accepted answer! One more little thing: I presume with tab bar icons they are the same as any other icon - If I have named the icon Picture.png, then I also have to include another icon with twice the resolution named Picture@2x.png (which iOS will automatically select if it is being view on a retina display)?

Comment: @Giovanni If you want your app to look decent on a Retina display, yes.